# What is the naming convention for function parameters that accept the same data frame as input?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I have read the https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/ guideline for the naming conventions of python code.

What I did not find is the convention for naming function parameters when there are multiple functions that have a data frame as input.

Something like:

```
def func_1(df): 
  #Do something 

def func_2(df): 
  #Do something 

def func_3(df): 
  #Do something
```

I read this similar post which talks about the same issue but it was posted almost 10 years ago: [Parameter naming convention in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465921/parameter-naming-convention-in-python)

And it basically says that one should use heuristic methods for naming parameters.

The problem is if you have many functions, it might not be easy to come up with unique names for each function parameter. So I'd like to know if there is an updated pythonic convention for how to name function parameters that are similar in type.

Comment: Why would you need unique names at all?  They're different functions.  The parameter names will not conflict with each other.

Comment: There is a chance that one function might modify the original data and then this could propagate throughout the code

Comment: And using different names prevents that how, exactly?

Comment: I honestly don't see anything wrong with naming them all as `df`. As long as each function does its own specific thing (get a `df`, do operations on it, return the same `df` or not), then it shouldn't matter how _other_ functions are doing on their own inputs. What's more important is the naming of the functions themselves, so that it's clear on the caller code which set of functions to call and in what sequence.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.